# Implementing a traversal with dynamic depth

Tags: java, neo4j, traversal, neo4j-embedded

Is it possible to create a traversal in java using neo4j that keeps a state for the duration of the traversal?

For example, I need an `Evaluator` that is almost identical to `toDepth()`, except that the depth at the current node is based on another comparison. Say that you had a linked list with 20 items, and you wanted the 10th [valid] one, meaning that some of the items had a particular property flag excluding them from the count. So the final returned item might actually be the 12th in the `Path`.

The only efficient way I can think of doing this is being able to store some state variable that is accessible to each individual evaluation. Is that possible?

I understand that I could write my own custom traversing functions to do this, but it would be nice if I could build it into the Traversal Framework.

Comment: I think you have to write your own custom functions to do this.  Evaluators shouldn't require state though, because each time a traversal is evaluated it gives you the entire path in question.   But worth noting -- evaluators just tell you whether or not to continue traversing they don't give you traversal results.

Comment: Yes it does give you the entire path, but is entirely inefficient for doing something like I am trying above. I can think of a few scenarios where keeping state during a traversal would be quite useful.

Comment: There is state keeping in PathExpander. So go and read the javadocs there and implement your logic with such a PathExpander instead. I think Evaluators should be aware of that state as well.

Comment: Thanks. Reading through the docs now. Do you know of any examples by any chance?